# Why is gRPC so much slower than an HTTP API sending an array

Tags: rest, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-node

I'm doing load tests between services implemented in Node.JS, both services on the same machine connected through `localhost`.

There are REST and gRPC client & server files. The main goal is to prove that gRPC is faster than an HTTP call because the use of HTTP/2, the use of protocol buffers that are more efficient than code/decode JSON...

But in my tests (sending an integer array) gRPC is so much slower.

The code is very simple for boths implementations, I have an auxiliar class to generate objects with sizes (in MB): 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 20. REST and gRPC server uses this auxiliar class so the object to send is the same.

The object send in the payload is like this:

```js
{
  message: "Hello world",
  array: []
}
```

Where the array is filled with numbers until get the desired size.

And my .proto is like this:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

service ExampleService {
    rpc GetExample (Size) returns (Example) {}
}

message Size {
    int32 size = 1;
}

message Example {
   string message = 1;
   repeated int32 array = 2;
}
```

Also I've running the application measuring only one call, to not create a loop and find the average, and also to not handle measuring time with callbacks. So I'm running the application 10 times and calculating the average.

REST server:

```js
app.get('/:size',(req,res) => {
    const size = req.params.size
    res.status(200).send(objects[size])
})
```

REST client:

```js
const start = performance.now()
const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/${size}`)
const end = performance.now()
```

gRPC server:

```js
getExample:(call, callback) => {
    callback(null, objects.objects[call.request.size])
}
```

And gRPC client:

```js
const start = performance.now()
client.getExample({ size: size }, (error, response) => {
    const end = performance.now()
})
```

To do more efficently I have tried:

1. Compress data like this:

```js
let server = new grpc.Server({
    'grpc.default_compression_level': 3, // (1->Low -- 3->High)
});
```

I know I can use `streaming` to get data and iterate over the array but I want to prove the "same call" in both methods.

And the difference is so big.

Other thing I've seen is that times using REST way are more "lineal" the difference between times is small, but using gRPC one call sending 2MB can be 220ms and the next one 500ms.

Here is the final comparision, as you can see the difference is considerably big.

Data:

| Size (MB) | REST (ms) | gRPC (ms) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0,125 | 37.98976998329162 | 35.5489800453186 |
| 0,25 | 40.03781998157501 | 46.077759981155396 |
| 0,5 | 51.35283002853394 | 59.37109994888306 |
| 1 | 63.4725800037384 | 166.7616500457128 |
| 2 | 95.76031665007274 | 394.2442199707031 |
| 5 | 261.9365399837494 | 804.1371199131012 |
| 20 | 713.1867599964141 | 5492.330539941788 |

[image]

But I thought... maybe the array field can't be decode in an efficient way, maybe is the integer number which is not heavy for JSON... I don't know, so I'm going to try to send a string, a very huge large string.

So my proto file now looks like this:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

service ExampleService {
    rpc GetExample (Size) returns (Example) {}
}

message Size {
    int32 size = 1;
}

message Example {
   string message = 1;
   string array = 2;
}
```

Now the object send is like this:

```js
{
  message: "Hello world",
  array: "text to reach the desired MB"
}
```

And results are so differents, now gRPC is much more efficient.

Data:

| Size (MB) | REST (ms) | gRPC (ms) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0,125 | 30.672580003738403 | 25.028959941864013 |
| 0,25 | 33.568540048599246 | 25.366739988327026 |
| 0,5 | 37.19938006401062 | 27.539460039138795 |
| 1 | 46.4020166794459 | 28.798949996630352 |
| 2 | 57.50188330809275 | 35.45066670576731 |
| 5 | 107.39933327833812 | 48.90079998970032 |
| 20 | 313.4138665994008 | 136.4138500293096 |

[image]

And the question: So, why sending an integer array is not as efficient as sending an string? Is the way protobuf encode/decode arrays? Is not efficient send `repeated` values?  Is related with the language (JS)?

Comment: have you found anything so far?

Comment: Nothing yet @omid

Comment: I was just moving to gRPC from HTTP, and saw your question, thanks for saving my time :D have you found a faster way and do you have any advice for sending large arrays?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason gRPC -- well, really protobufs -- doesn’t scale well in your example is that every entry of your `repeated` field results in protobuf needing to decode a separate field, and there is overhead related to that. You can see more details about the encoding of repeated fields in the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#optional). You're using `proto3`, so at least you don't need to specify the [`[packed=true]` option](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#packed), although that helps somewhat if you're on `proto2`.

The reason switching to a `string` or `bytes` field speeds it up so much is that there is only a constant decoding cost for this field which doesn't scale with the amount of data that's encoded in the field (not sure about JS though, which might need to create a copy of the data, but clearly that is still much faster than actually parsing the data). Just make sure your protocol defines what format / endianness the data in the field is :-)

Answering your question at a higher level, sending multiple megabytes in a single API call is *usually* not an amazing idea anyway -- it ties up a thread on both the server and client for a long time which forces you to use multithreading or async code to get reasonable performance. (Admittedly might be less of an issue since you are used to writing async stuff on Node, but there's still only so many CPUs to burn on the server.)

Depending on what you're actually trying to do, a common pattern can be to write the data to a file in a shared storage system (S3, etc.) and pass the filename to the other service, which can then download it when it's actually needed.

Comment: this helped me to understand the issue

Comment: @0xh8h how did u mitigate the issue?

Comment: @JoelBlum: unfortunately I didn't resolve this issue yet. We have to use REST for this purpose